# Using status_module with ProxyPass Virtual Hosts in Apache (Windows)

Tags: windows, apache

I've been playing around with the status_module for a bit now but I cannot seem to apply it to the Virtual Hosts I want as described here:

https://techexpert.tips/apache/apache-mod_status-installation/

https://www.quickhost.uk/blog/2021/09/22/how-to-enable-the-apache-mod_status-page/

I'm able to load /server-status on the root Virtual Host:

http://servername.example.com:50436/server-status?auto

```
<VirtualHost *:50436>
    DocumentRoot "C:/My/Sample/Web/App/htdocs"
</VirtualHost>
```

With the following config:

```
<IfModule status_module>
    <Location /server-status>
            SetHandler server-status
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Location>
    ExtendedStatus On
    <IfModule proxy_module>
            ProxyStatus On
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

I was hoping to add some granularity and add this status_module to each of my 4 Virtual Hosts, so I applied the following config, as seen in the links above (1 as a sample):

```
<VirtualHost *:50486>
    DocumentRoot "C:/My/Second/Web/App/htdocs"
    ProxyPreserveHost Off
    ProxyPass / http://servername:50486/app/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://servername:50486/app/
<Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

When navigating to http://servername.example.com:50486/server-status?auto it presents a 404 error

The one thing I've noticed is that none of the examples online illustrate adding the status_module to a Virtual Host that's using a ProxyPass configuration.  Is that a limitation or not possible?

OS: Windows Server DataCenter 2019